authMiddleware() is deprecated in nextjs
import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";

export default authMiddleware();

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};

authmiddlware is showing deprecated. What is an alternative to it ?

Clerk has replaced authMiddleware with clerkMiddleware.
Reference: https://clerk.com/docs/references/nextjs/auth-middleware
